# Remove items from the IEnumerable<T> is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, ienumerable

I am trying to remove the objects from the `IEnumerable<ImportDataMappingModel> GridList`

I tried with the below options but non of them is working.

`value` is a property in `ImportDataMappingModel`

```
GridList.ToList().RemoveAll(o => o.value==null);
GridList=GridList.TakeWhile(o => o.value!=null);
```

Comment: Please describe "not working"

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
GridList = GridList.Where(o => o.value != null).ToList();
```

Your first attempt, `GridList.ToList().RemoveAll(o => o.value==null)`, creates a copy of the list (the `ToList()` call) and then modifies that copy, leaving the original list unchanged.

Your second attempt, `GridList=GridList.TakeWhile(o => o.value!=null)`, creates an enumerable that, when enumerated, will return all non-null items that precede the first null item (if any).  But it does not actually enumerate the new enumerable, so you never actually create that new collection.

To correct the second attempt, you need to do two things:

1. Replace TakeWhile with Where.  For example, if you have a list with three entries, the first and third of which are not null, while the second is null, TakeWhile will return only the first item.  If you want all non-null items, you need to use Where instead.
2. Call ToList() to copy the items selected by the Where enumerator into a new list.

Comment: @psubsee2003 all the other answers explain what is wrong.  None of them, however, proposes the solution that OP seems to want.

Comment: And now you have my +1

Answer (score 4):

ToList returns a copy of your GridList and you are modifying it, not original GridList

Answer (score 4):

This does not work because it is working on a copy and that copy is not assigned to anything.

```
GridList.ToList().RemoveAll(o => o.value==null);
```

The fix would be:

```
var list = GridList.ToList(); //create copy
list.RemoveAll(o => o.value==null); //work on copy
GridList = list; //assign copy to gridlist
```

This [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548775%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) version doesn't work because it will stop taking when `o.value==null`, (note it will work in the case where everything you don't want is on the end!):

```
GridList = GridList.TakeWhile(o => o.value!=null);
```

The fix would be to use where:

```
GridList = GridList.Where(o => o.value!=null);
```

Comment: end means if i have 10 items then all the null items should be at the end.

Comment: I am saying TakeWhile would appear to work if items on the end are `o.value==null`

Comment: perhaps lazy execution of the LINQ query is to blame for the issue with the 2nd query?

Answer (score 2):

You can't `Remove` items from an `IEnumerable<T>`, because it is not meant to be modifiable.

Try using an `ICollection<T>`

Answer (score 1):

```
GridList.ToList().RemoveAll(o => o.value==null));
```

This code won't do what you want since A call to '.ToList()' creates a new instance of List<>, different from GridList. So this code will actually remove all the null-valued items from the new list instance, and not from 'GridList'.

```
GridList = GridList.TakeWhile(o => o.value!=null);
```

This code will actually do what you expect, but since Linq commands are differed executing, simply calling TakeWhile() will not execute immediately, but only after you'll try to read the items of GridList. If you want to force the execution, you should call ".ToList()" or ".ToArray()" at the end, i.e.:

```
GridList = GridList.TakeWhile(o => o.value!=null).ToList();
```